# long vs wide, tidy vs efficient

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm finding some suboptimal steps in my current data analysis workflow when it comes to switching between long and wide formats. Consider the three traces shown below, with common `x` values,

[image]

My data is in long format, useful for plotting and all sorts of pipy things, but for some parts of the analysis it seems much easier to deal with a wide (matrix-like) format. For instance, in this dummy example, I might want to set the baseline to 0 for all traces, by subtracting the average of each trace between 0 and 0.25 (shaded grey area).

*I cannot find an easy way to do this sort of thing in long format.*

My current strategy is to switch back to wide format, but i) I never remember the correct syntax for dcast/reshape, ii) it's quite inefficient to keep going back and forth between the two.

```
dwide <- reshape2::dcast(dlong, x~..., value.var="y")
dwide[,-1] <- sweep(dwide[,-1], 2, colMeans(dwide[dwide$x < 0.25, -1]), FUN="-")
dlong2 <- melt(dwide, id="x")
```

[image]

Have I missed some tools that could help? I'm open to data.table suggestions.

---

Full reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

## dummy data as noisy lorentzian-shaped peaks with random offset

set.seed(1234)
fake_data <- function(a, x = seq(0, 1, length=100)){ 
  data.frame(x = x, 
             y = jitter(1e-3 / ((x - a)^2 + 1e-3) + runif(1,0,1), 
                   amount = 0.1))
}

## apply function to all combinations of parameters (one here)
dlong <- plyr::mdply(data.frame(a = c(0.4,0.5,0.6)), fake_data)

ggplot(dlong, aes(x, y, colour=factor(a))) + geom_line() +
  annotate("rect", xmin=-Inf, xmax=0.25, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill="grey", alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_minimal()

dwide <- reshape2::dcast(dlong, x~..., value.var="y")
str(dwide)

dwide[,-1] <- sweep(dwide[,-1], 2, colMeans(dwide[dwide$x < 0.25, -1]), FUN="-")
dlong2 <- melt(dwide, id="x")

ggplot(dlong2, aes(x, value, colour=variable)) + geom_line()  +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: I find `tidyr`'s `gather` and `spread` require less thought than `reshape2`, with the exception that `spread` can be very finicky about indices. Here, `dwide <- dlong %>% spread(a, y)` and `dlong2 <- dwide %>% gather(variable, value, -x)` (or use `a` and `y` instead of `variable` and `value` to keep original names).

Comment: I agree, they do seem more intuitive. I'll try to use them more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe your minimal example was too trivial to capture all the cases where you might want to go long to wide to long. But for your example at least, I would typically use data.table for this kind of operation:

```
setDT(dlong)[, y2 := y - mean(y[x < 0.25]), by=a]

ggplot(dlong, aes(x, y2, colour=factor(a))) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Breaking this down:

- `by = a` groups the data so that the operation in the 2nd argument of `[`.data.table is applied to subsets of dlong corresponding to each value of a
- `y2 := y - mean(y[x < 0.25])` is therefore calculated for each value of a, separately
- `:=` is a special operator in data.table that provides assignment by reference rather than assignment by copying (its very efficient)
- the 1st argument of `[`.datat.table was left blank here, because we wish to operate on all rows of the original dlong data.

Pretty much the same thing can be done with `dplyr` by

```
dlong %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  mutate(y2 = y - mean(y[x < 0.25]))
```

Comment: thanks, that sounds promising. I don't use data.table, so the syntax is a bit unfamiliar to me. You're right in that the example is perhaps a little too minimal... I'll see if I can present something more convincing.

Comment: In dplyr: `dlong %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(y2 = y - mean(y[x < 0.25])) %>% ggplot(aes(x, y2, colour = factor(a))) + geom_line() + theme_minimal()`